# Terminal vim color scheme keeps reverting

Tags: vim, terminal

I am trying to install the atom-dark-256 colorscheme into my terminal vim.
I have the file saved in my `.vim/colors` directory.

The colorscheme changes as I would like when I am in vim and type `:colorscheme atom-dark-256`

However if I put the following line into my .vimrc file:

```
colorscheme atom-dark-256
```

and save it, it works but as soon as I exit and come back into vim it reverts to the default color scheme.

Comment: Can you post your `vimrc`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main possibilities: your vimrc is not being loaded, or something is overwriting your colorscheme setting (perhaps a plugin or an [`autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3aautocmd)).

You can check if you vimrc is being loaded using the [`scriptnames`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3ascriptnames), or by inserting an error in the file and checking that Vim complains about it in the initialization.

You can debug your vimrc by following [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1405) or the explanation at [Vim-FAQ  2.5 - Have I found a bug in Vim?](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5)